# Caret train: Error reproducing rpart. "Error in na.fail.default [on target class] missing values in object"

Tags: r, r-caret, rpart

**The data**
I'm working with a certain dataset, having all numeric features except for my categoric target which has 3 possible values. Target has no missing values, but is highly unbalanced: class_1 ~ 600 samples; class_2 ~700 samples; class_3 ~ 235000 samples.
Predictor varibles have na's and my approach is not to impute them. So I'm looking to tune trees.

**My problem**
I successfully ran a rpart model, with no problem fitting nor predicting.
Parameters and code as follows:

```
model  <- rpart("target ~ .",
                 data = train_data,
                 xval = 0,
                 cp = -0.3, 
                 minsplit = 80,
                 minbucket = 1,
                 maxdepth = 8)
```

Now I want to work with caret for cross-validating, hyperparameter tuning, and so.
I tried to reproduce rpart code as follows:

```
model <- train(target ~.,
               data = train_data,
               method = "rpart",
               control = rpart.control(xval = 0,cp = -0.3,minsplit = 80,
                                         minbucket = 1,maxdepth = 8)
```

**The error**
Show in New Window

```
Error in na.fail.default(list(target = c("Class 1", "Class 1",  : 
  missing values in object
```

**What I tried**
I searched for the error, and I interpret from the message that the problem is in target's null values -which I don't have!-
Can I get some advice to asses the problem? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: can you add output of `dput(train_data)` ?

Comment: what happens if you include in the `train` call: `na.action = na.pass`? It would me much easier to help you if you could reproduce this behavior with a data set we have access to, preferably an inbuilt one.

Comment: Thank you both. It just needed na.pass. I thought that, given rpart handled them without any parameter needed, caret should do the same. Apologies for the basic question. Should I erase the topic? Answer myself? My new error is "Warning: model fit failed for Resample.." for all resamples but that's a different affair.

Comment: if you think an answer would help others then add it, if not then choose between leaving the question so comments can help others and deleting. Basically its is your choice. There are no hard rules.